# extension of function in an abstract metric space

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, real-analysis

my question is the following.(Maybe my title is not quite proper for this question):

Let $(E,d)$ be a Polish space (or a separable metric space), let $\xi: E\to R_+$ be a Lipschitz function. Now set $B_i=\{x\in E: d(x,0)\le i \}$ for $i=1,2$. Could we find a Lipschitz function $\eta: E\to R_+$ such that

$$\xi(x)=\eta(x),~ \forall x\in B_1$$

and

$$\eta(x)=0,~ \forall x\notin B_2$$

I know that this is a very general result existing in a lot of references. But I can not find such a reference to confirm the existence of $\eta$. Could someone give a reply? Thx a lot!

Comment: The following result in the Euclidean case can be found, for example, in [these lecture notes](http://www.math.jyu.fi/research/reports/rep100.pdf):
"Let $M$ be a metric space and $A\subset M$ any set. If $f:A\to\mathbb R$ is $L$-Lipschitz, then it has an extension to $M$ which is also $L$-Lipschitz."
The proof given in the notes is valid in this generality.
(See Theorem 2.3.)
One possible extension is provided by $\bar{f}(x)=\inf_{a\in A}(f(a)+Ld(x,a))$.
I don't know a reference for the theorem in this generality, though, if you need one.

Comment: Thx for the reply, but I think the $\bar{f}$ does not satisfy: $\bar{f}|_{B^c}=0$, where $B$ is some open set including $A$

Comment: In your case, take $A=B_1\cup C_2^c$ and define $f=\xi$ in $B_1$ and $f=0$ in $B_2$. Then it is a matter of extending a Lipschitz function.

Comment: Along @Joonas Ilmavirta's line, let $\ g:B_1\cup(X\setminus B_2)\ $ be an extension of $\ \xi\ $ which is $\ 0\ $ on $\ X\setminus B_2.\ $ Let $\ L\ $ be the Lipschitz constant for $\ \xi.\ $ Then $\ L\ $ is a Lipschitz constant for $\ g.\ $ Etc. It is a simple exercise, not a research question.

Comment: It seems that my previous comment has a couple of typos. I meant to say that $A=B_1\cup B_2^c$, $f=\xi$ in $B_1$ and $f=0$ in $B_2^c$.

Comment: You can find basic Lipschitz extension theorems, including the non linear Hahn-Banach theorem of of McShane-Whitney and Kirszbraun's extension theorem in Heinonen's lecture notes       http://www.math.jyu.fi/research/reports/rep100.pdf

Comment: @BillJohnson, my first comment actually includes a (barely visible) link to the same notes. I didn't check it very thoroughly for the most general extension theorems, though.

Comment: Hey, @Joonas, make them visible :-)

Comment: Thx for the reply. I have read the notes and thx again. Sorry for that my question is not of research level...

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński, if I recall correctly, people have asked at meta for more visible links in comments but to little avail. It _should_ be enough to make a link following the markdown instructions.

Comment: why don't you just multiply by some Lipschitz cut-off, e.g. $\eta(x):=\xi(x)\min\big(1, (2-d(x,O))_+\big)$.